# $\{x_1,x_2\}$ linearly independent. $\{x_1,x_2,u,v\}$, $\{x_1,x_2,w,z\}$ are basis => $\{u,v,w,z\}$ not a basis?

Tags: vector-spaces, independence

Let $V$ be a vector space of $\dim(V)=4$, and $\{x_1,x_2\}$ are linearly independent in $V$.

We can complete it to a basis of $V$: $B_1=\{x_1,x_2,u,v\}$ and another one $B_1=\{x_1,x_2,w,z\}$.

Is $C=\{u,v,w,z\}$ necessarily **not** a basis for $V$?

Comment: Consider $x_1=(1,0,0,0)$, $x_2=(0,1,0,0)$, $u=(0,0,1,0)$, $v=(0,0,0,1)$, $w=(1,0,1,0)$, $v=(0,1,0,1)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the vector space $\mathbb{R}^4$ and let $e_1, e_2, e_3, e_4$ denote the standard basis. Consider the bases
$$\{e_1, e_2, e_3+e_1,e_4+e_2\}$$
and
$$\{e_1, e_2, e_3+2e_1, e_4+2e_2\}.$$
Then
$$\{e_3+e_1,e_4+e_2,e_3+2e_1,e_4+2e_2\}$$ is also a basis since:
$$e_1 = (e_3+2e_1)-(e_3+e_1),$$
$$e_2 = (e_4+2e_2)-(e_4+e_2),$$
$$e_3 = 2(e_3+e_1)-(e_3+2e_1),$$
$$e_4 = 2(e_4+e_2)-(e_4+2e_2).$$